Initialise running parallel tests using a filter
Not too sure if running parallel testing is the right option for what i am trying to achieve.
So essentially we have a set of API tests and a set of UI tests where i have a filter on each test fixture by category e.g. [TestFixture, Category("API")] or [TestFixture, Category("UI")]. What i want is to run both sets of test using one pipeline but running the API and UI tests completely independant but at the same time.
Is there an option to configure UI tests running on one agent and the API tests running on another agent. Below is my current agent job set up:

I have considered just turning the parallel option on but with most of out test fixtures each test will depend on each other so running tests in different locations is not ideal as it could leave data in a bad state or have failures because one test was meant to run first etc. I have not made any code changes to attempt to run tests in parallel.

You can make use of 2 separate jobs in the pipeline one for API Tests and another one for UI Tests based on its filter:-
I have tried to run the yaml pipeline with two separate Jobs one for API_Tests and another for UI_Tests  like below:-
trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

jobs:
- job: API_Tests
  displayName: 'Run API Tests'
  pool:
    vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
  steps:
  - task: UseDotNet@2
    inputs:
      packageType: 'sdk'
      version: '5.x'
      installationPath: $(Agent.ToolsDirectory)/dotnet
  - script: |
      dotnet restore
      dotnet build --configuration Release
    displayName: 'Restore and Build'
  - script: |
      dotnet test --configuration Release --filter TestCategory=API
    displayName: 'Run API Tests'

- job: UI_Tests
  displayName: 'Run UI Tests'
  pool:
    vmImage: 'windows-latest'
  steps:
  - task: UseDotNet@2
    inputs:
      packageType: 'sdk'
      version: '5.x'
      installationPath: $(Agent.ToolsDirectory)/dotnet
  - script: |
      dotnet restore
      dotnet build --configuration Release
    displayName: 'Restore and Build'
  - script: |
      dotnet test --configuration Release --filter TestCategory=UI
    displayName: 'Run UI Tests'


Output:-

For Release pipeline:-
Approach1)
I have ran TestAPI in separate agent and job and TestUI in separate agent and job
TestAPI:-

Output:-

TestUI:-

Output:-

Approach2) with command line dotnet scripts
TestAPI:-



TestUI:-




Thank you i will give this a try. This seems like the most logical solution
